# jenkins pipeline build NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I use in jenkins version 2.147, openjdk10

```
node{
    echo 'Hello'
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHQ1d.png)
I'm trying pipeline default setting build, but this show error.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Go to manage Jenkins->plugin manager and check if all of your plugins are updated.